# How do you specify a worksheet instead of ActiveSheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro and it created a With loop on the "ActiveSheet".  I want to specify which worksheet so I can create a button with that macro contained within it and it will refer to the correct worksheet. It should be simple syntax in vba how to specify a specific worksheet instead of "With ActiveSheet" - I'm just unfamiliar with vba syntax.

Comment: Use the syntax `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet_name")`

Comment: This was perfect and so simple.  Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First declare a variable like this

```
Dim wk As Worksheet
```

Then Set it to any worksheet you want using any of the following syntax's. These are just a few ways there are other ways too.

```
Set wk = Sheet1   'Sheet1 is the sheet Number 
Set wk = Worksheets("Sheet1")   'Sheet1 is the sheet Name.
Set wk = Worksheets(1)   '1 is the Worksheet Index Number
```

Then you can do things with that variable like this

```
wk.Name = "NewName of Worksheet"    
wk.Range("A1") = "Assigning something to range A1 of that worksheet"
```